# Text Cursor animation using Geometry Nodes

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I want to make an animation of a text cursor going back and forth.
[image: Caret animated using keyframes]
Right now, I'm using a plane and animating it's position using keyframes, which is imprecise and annoying.

I have tried inserting a pipe `|` character in the middle of the text, but that pushes the text forwards/backwards which is not what I'm looking for.

[image: Caret animated with geometry nodes using a pipe character]

Is there a way to animate a text cursor in a way shown above (using a position value), but so text doesn't get pushed forwards/backwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can help...

I'm using a mesh island node to individually select each of the characters, and then using a bounding box node to find where the cursor should be relative to that character. I'm then setting my cursor x position to match, with some extra scene time nodes to make it blink :)
[image: the nodes]
[image: the cursor]

Comment: It works great, but unfortunately it skips spaces...